# Generic function issue - Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'T'

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems I still don't "get" generics ... I want a general function to load a user control which inherently calls Page.LoadControl() but I am getting the error above when trying to make it work.

Here is a mock up of the code I use to load the control:

```
MyControl Ctrl = MyUtilClass.LoadControl(Page, "MyControl");
```

and then in MyUtilClass:

```
internal static T LoadControl<T>(Page P, string ControlName)
{
    return (T)P.LoadControl(String.Format("~/{0}{1}.ascx", WebGlobals.cControlDir, ControlName));
}
```

I am obviously doing something wrong but my understanding was the compiler would look at the type of var I am trying to assign the result of this function to and be able to cast the result as that type.

Comment: `MyUtilClass.LoadControl(...);` alone is a valid statement (which throws away the return value) (and if it wasn't a generic method...). How would it calculate T from that? You need to specify T when calling, `MyUtilClass.LoadControl<MyControl>(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to constrain your generic function to `Control`s only, otherwise `T` is too generic for your purposes.

```
internal static T LoadControl<T>(Page P, string ControlName)
    where T : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

You could do this but I'm not sure its worth the extra complexity over the non generic approach in [Daniel Hilgarth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10102243/659190).

```
internal static void LoadControl<T>(Page P, 
                                     string ControlName
                                     out T control)
    where T : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    control = (T)P.LoadControl(
                   String.Format("~/{0}{1}.ascx",
                                    WebGlobals.cControlDir, 
                                    ControlName));
}
```

calling like this

```
MyControl myControl;
LoadControl(page, "MyControl", myControl);
```

Comment: Ok great, that sorts the initial problem but I am now getting `The type arguments for method 'MyUtilClass.LoadControl<T>(System.Web.UI.Page, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @webnoob, how is recieving variable of the call declared, with `var`?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand. It's declared like `MyControl Ctrl` if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Jodrell: That's irrelevant. Generic argument types are not inferred from the type of the variable the return value is assigned to.

Comment: @webnoob, you need to explicitly pass the type using the angle brackets, `<thetype>`.

Comment: @Jodrell - Ah ok, gottcha. This is now working: `MyControl Ctrl = MyUtilClass.LoadControl<MyControl>(Page, "MyControl");`

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, on reflection you are right. I confused myself with the `TryParse` pattern but, that uses the type of the `out` parameter (obviously.)

Comment: @webnoob, the non generic approach in Daniel Hilgarth's answer should be considered here

Comment: @Jodrell - Yes, I decided on that as well. Thanks for your help. I am still pleased I know why the previous code wouldn't work though and have left this as the answer as it answered the actual problem.

Comment: @webnoob refined approach added

Answer (score 3):

You don't need generics for this. Simply make your method return `Control`:

```
internal static System.Web.UI.Control LoadControl(Page P, string ControlName)
{
    return P.LoadControl(String.Format("~/{0}{1}.ascx", WebGlobals.cControlDir,
                                                        ControlName));
}
```

If you put this method in a static class, you can make an extension method out of it, note the `this` before the first parameter of the method:

```
internal static System.Web.UI.Control LoadControl(this Page P, string ControlName)
{
    return P.LoadControl(String.Format("~/{0}{1}.ascx", WebGlobals.cControlDir, 
                                                        ControlName));
}
```

you can now call it like this:

```
var control = yourPage.LoadControl(controlName);
```

---

If you really want to have a `MyControl` instance, change the method to this:

```
internal static MyControl LoadControl(this Page P, string ControlName)
{
    return (MyControl)P.LoadControl(String.Format("~/{0}{1}.ascx", 
                                    WebGlobals.cControlDir, 
                                    ControlName));
}
```

Comment: But I want the result to be `MyControl` which is a class itself that inherits off Control. `public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl`

Comment: All controls are `Control`s (+1 by the way)

Comment: @webnoob: In that case make the method return `MyControl` and cast the result of `P.LoadControl` to `MyControl`, see update. Still no reason for a generic method.

Comment: @Jodrell - Yes but I will have specific properties published against MyControl that I will want to access once the control has been loaded and was trying to avoid casting each time I load a control.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I don't just have one control. Once this is finished I will have 100's which would make a general function pointless if it couldn't return the actual type.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Just re-read your comment in line with the change I have had to make (passing the type through to the generic) and you are probably right. I am having to cast the generic now anyway so I guess using a generic is confusing matters.